# How to make strings linearly independent

Tags: matrices

Whatever real numbers George wrote on the black squares of the chessboard
for example, Sam can fill in the white cells so that you get a rank 8 matrix. Prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity matrix $I$ has rank 8 and is zero on all the black squares. If $M$ is the matrix written by George, then $M + x I$ has rank 8 when $x$ is large enough. In fact there are at most 8 numbers $x$ for which its rank is not 8.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but what are these x's?

Comment: @Elias The idea is that Sam writes $x$ on the diagonal (which consists of white squares) and $0$ on the other white squares.